# MySQL get top 10 ranked by heat without sorting the whole dataset

Tags: mysql

## Background

My Table `discussion` consists of billions of rows with millions distinct `topic`s:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)     | No   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| topic   | varchar(32) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| content | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

## Problem

I want the top 10 topic(ranked by the time it was mentioned) and it costs minutes to sort the whole dataset grouped by topic (there are millions distinct topics).

the existing SQL:

```
select (select uuid()) id, topic, count(*) heat
from discussion
group by topic order by heat desc limit 0, 10
```

## Question

Is there a method in MySQL to get the top 10 without sorting the whole dataset(like selection sort or heap sort).

Or is there any other ways to finish this in seconds?

Comment: Does this table have any indices?

Comment: there is an `topic` index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want the **top** 10, MySQL will **have** to sort the entire dataset first.
There's just no other way.

You'd get better performance using a columnar store, or if your use-case allows you, a Redis cache using a sorted set (google: redis leaderboard, it's a classic use-case).

Comment: won't it cost a lot to transfer millions of data from MySQL to Redis? I think it's hard to save the data in Redis because the column `heat` which I want to sort by is virtual. Do I miss something?

Comment: Using the cache is a great method, but is there a way to make this operation timely?

Comment: @kasheemlew What do you mean by timely? Whenever you write to MySQL, you **also** write to Redis: `ZINCRBY topics_to_msgcount 1 "mytopic"` (increment "mytopic" [could also be the ID] for a sorted set called `topics_to_msgcount`). To get the sorted results `ZREVRANGE topics_to_msgcount 0 -1 WITHSCORES`. To delete anything but the top 10 results: `ZREMRANGEBYRANK topics_to_msgcount 0 -11`